# Pythonic way to introduce multiple different file-paths in pytest

Tags: python, variables, module, pytest, filepath

I have a pytest script that has roughly 20 different test. Each test collects data and stores that data in specified file-paths. Each file-path is individually defined within each test. For example:

```
def test_1():
gfx = open('path/to/file_1')
do something

def test_2():
focus = open('path/to/file_2')
do something

def test_3():
data = open('path/to_1/file_3')
do something
```

The problem is, I am in the process of transferring these scripts to a new server. Obviously, this server now has different directories that do not match my old defined ones.

My question is, what is the most Pythonic way to introduce file-paths for pytest? Would it be best to have variables defined that are easily modified? Or is there a better way?

If more information or clarity is needed please let me know.

Comment: is the path the same for all tests? if yes, would you like to give the path as a command line option for pytest?

Comment: The base path is i.e. /user/name/Desktop/folder is the same however after that is different for each test. Which is why I thought it might make sense to have a variable for the base path and then just add the rest of the path within each test. I have updated the summary with a correct example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be obvious, but in general to avoid such problems, tests should include the data that is needed for them. If the data (file) is big, perhaps you can create a minimal example for your test? That would be the cleanest solution.

If that is not possible, e.g. the minimal data (file) is still too big and is stored separately, so the exact location of the path could differ from machine to machine. I would use an environment variable, where the base path - as you already suggested in your comment - is set.

```
import os

try:
    test_data_base_path = os.environ['test_data_base_path']
except KeyError:
    print('Could not get environment variable "test_data_base_path". '
          'This is needed for the tests!')
    raise


def test_1():
    gfx = open(os.path.join(test_data_base_path, 'subfolder', 'to', 'file_1'))
    # do something

def test_2():
    focus = open(os.path.join(test_data_base_path, 'subfolder', 'to', 'file_2'))
    # do something

# ...
```

How to set the `test_data_base_path` environment variable depends on how you run your tests. If you need it globally, you can do that via your OS. If you start your tests via an IDE, you can usually set them directly there.

Comment: This seems like the solution I was thinking about but could not think how to do. I will need to try it out. I really appreciate the quick response!